# PiPico Quad Spi library to controll NOR flash modules

Tags: spi, memory, pi-pico

I need to use quad SPI NOR flash modules (W25Q128JV) for a project and I bought a Pi Pico as a simple way of validating the design before moving to an FPGA for the final project (the project is real-time image processing so won't be able to use a slow MCU like pico, but for validating the design it is good enough). As far as I can tell from googling, there is no built-in library to do this. Before implementing my own library in C, I thought I'd ask here first in case there is one and I just can't find it.
Also, would it be ok to bit-bang the signals or is there a way to use the PIO for this?

I'm a complete beginner when it comes to Pi Pico and have written 0 lines of code for it before, so I'm not sure what it is capable of, but I do have a fairly decent understanding of programming and electronics.

Please let me know what the best approach would be, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I know this was posted a while ago, but my comment would be that you'd be needing to implement software SPI for QSPI because the RP2040 only has two hardware SPI interfaces.

Comment: comments do not belong in the answer section

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).